# How can I change name of dynamically generated URL in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, url

I'm having dynamic url for my each search result in Codeigniter, but I want to know how can I change my url. For example right now I'm having the url something like this:

```
www.xyz.com/vendor/vendor_details?iuL80rpoEMxCi89uK6rIyTgqCGuagQ+BUoUnvyBdx09EawMiFfnaB+q3Q8YyBSFwbOVw8+32ZInJrjE2I42teA==
```

but I want it like this:

```
www.xyz.com/Delhi/Balaji-Courier-And-Cargo-Bharat-Singh-Market-Opposite-B-7-Petrol-Pump-Vasant-Kunj/011P1238505881A9D9W7_BZDET?xid=RGVsaGkgSW50ZXJuYXRpb25hbCBDb3VyaWVyIFNlcnZpY2VzIEhhbWlsdG9uIFJvYWQ=
```

Comment: you can use CodeIgniter [URI Routing](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html)

Comment: @suhindra but how, can you give me some example.

Answer (score 2):

here the example

```
$route['vendor/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)']   = 'vendor/vendor_details/$3';
```

Answer (score 0):

See this Documentation here: [routing](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html)

You want to add

> www.example.com/city/address/related_id

This Example can help you to get that.

Here are a few routing examples:

```
$route['journals'] = 'blogs';
```

A URL containing the word “journals” in the first segment will be remapped to the “blogs” class.

```
$route[blog/Joe'] = 'blogs/users/34';
```

A URL containing the segments blog/Joe will be remapped to the “blogs” class and the “users” method. The ID will be set to “34”.

```
$route['product/(:any)'] = 'catalog/product_lookup';
```

A URL with “product” as the first segment and anything in the second will be remapped to the “catalog” class and the “product_lookup” method.

```
$route['product/(:num)'] = 'catalog/product_lookup_by_id/$1';
```

A URL with “product” as the first segment and a number in the second will be remapped to the “catalog” class and the “product_lookup_by_id” method passing in the match as a variable to the method.